# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I saw this in a book I am reading

[image]

I am a little bit confused because this Lemma implies that $\mathbb{R}$ is a group but I always were taught that a group is written in the form of $(X,*)$ were $X$ is some set and $*$ is some operation on $X$ like addition or multiplication. Yet this Lemma says that that $\mathbb{R}$ is group but $\mathbb{R}$ is just a set also if it is a group then with what operation is a group?

Comment: It is implied that the operation is either $+$ or $\times$, and in this case it is $+$.

Comment: @KennyLau, how do you know it is $+$?

Comment: By some boring convention, @gbd

Comment: @Kenny: And it is not closed. So?

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted "closed".

Comment: "This book" has a name, this way people can look it up and tell you what you missed a couple of pages earlier. BE SPECIFIC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, The name of the book is "Elements of topological Dynamics".

Comment: [Edit] this into the post please. With as full reference as you can make it.

Comment: @KennyLau ... and the fact that $(\Bbb R,\cdot)$ is not a group: $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli right, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that, formally speaking, a group is a set $X$ along with a binary operation $*$ on $X$: $G = (X,*)$. But in many cases, we abuse notation for the sake of simplicity when it is clear from context (or at least tradition) what the operation is, and in that case just refer to the set.

In the case of $\Bbb R$, the natural operations are $+$ and $\times$. But $(\Bbb R, \times)$ is not a group, because $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. Your book is therefore assuming that the operation is $+$. In the case of $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, the operation is $\times$. (Observe that $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is not closed under addition, so $(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\},+)$ is not a group.)

As another example, the group $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,+_n)$, i.e., the group of integers modulo $n$ with the operation of addition modulo $n$, is in some textbooks referred to as the group $\Bbb Z_n$.

Similarly, if we talk about the ring $\Bbb R$, we really mean (in all likelihood) the ring $(\Bbb R, +, \times)$.

Comment: Also, we say that $V$ is a vector space when we really mean $(V,+,\cdot)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb{R}$ is a group with the operation $+$.

$(\Bbb{R},+)$ group $\Rightarrow$ $+$ asociative; $$\exists c \in \Bbb{R}: a+c=a, \forall a \in R; \forall a \in R \exists b\in \Bbb{R}: a+b=c$$

$+$ associative

$a+c=a, c=0$

$a+b=c, a+b=0, -a=b$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is not a group under multiplication since $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.; $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is a group under multiplication.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.